# MKMapView not scaling to iPad view

Tags: ipad, mkmapview

I have a project that makes use of MKMapView, that works fine on an iphone. But when i run it on an ipad simulator or actual ipad, the MKMapView does not scale to cover its view. It retains the iPhone's viewscale.
Here is what it looks like on an iPhone-
[MKMapView on an iPhone](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvsu6dda4x2o3de/Screen%20Shot%202018-07-28%20at%205.59.45%20PM.png?dl=0)

And here is what it looks like on an iPad-
[MKMapView on an iPad](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jc6q86rzyodf011/Screen%20Shot%202018-07-28%20at%206.01.05%20PM.png?dl=0)

I have universalized the project from the project settings. What am I missing here. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add constraints to MapView.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution helped a lot.